# Apple Watch App runs on simulator but not physical device

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7, apple-watch

I am developing a relatively straightforward apple watch app that has two interface controllers.

[image]

When I deploy to the watch simulator, everything works as expected. However, since updating to the the Xcode 7, iOS 9, and WatchOS2 GM seeds, the application no longer run on the physical apple watch. It will launch, show the loading screen for ~10 sec and then crash with the following messages in the device log:

```
Sep 16 09:21:23 Andrews-AppleWatch iap2d[168] <Warning>: process com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp is now running the foreground
Sep 16 09:21:24 Andrews-AppleWatch pkd[127] <Warning>: assigning plug-in com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp.watchkitextension(1.0) to plugin sandbox
Sep 16 09:21:24 Andrews-AppleWatch pkd[127] <Warning>: enabling pid=92 for plug-in com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp.watchkitextension(1.0) 3E32E3AC-0701-49E8-9BEE-56528EFDF3C7 /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B54024B2-FED3-48A7-8F70-78C85C1C1DFB/PhotoGauge WatchKit App.app/PlugIns/PhotoGauge WatchKit Extension.appex
Sep 16 09:21:24 Andrews-AppleWatch kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[239] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/9BDCD39E-15AE-4019-A8D8-784A321EAF17 (sandbox)
Sep 16 09:21:24 Andrews-AppleWatch PhotoGauge WatchKit App[238] <Warning>: Requested a built-in font <UICTFont: 0x27b070> font-family: "Symbol"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 26.00ptg. Substituting system font
Sep 16 09:21:24 Andrews-AppleWatch PhotoGauge WatchKit App[238] <Warning>: Requested a built-in font <UICTFont: 0x27b070> font-family: "Symbol"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 26.00ptg. Substituting system font
Sep 16 09:21:24 Andrews-AppleWatch PhotoGauge WatchKit App[238] <Warning>: Requested a built-in font <UICTFont: 0x27b070> font-family: "Symbol"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 26.00ptg. Substituting system font
Sep 16 09:21:24 Andrews-AppleWatch iap2d[168] <Warning>: process com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp.watchkitextension is now running the foreground
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch diagnosticd[66] <Error>: error evaluating process info - pid: 239, punique: 239
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch ReportCrash[240] <Notice>: Formulating report for process[239] PhotoGauge WatchKit Extension
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch UserEventAgent[22] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch gizmoappd[92] <Warning>: plugin com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp.watchkitextension interrupted
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch gizmoappd[92] <Warning>: plugin com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp.watchkitextension invalidated
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch gizmoappd[92] <Notice>: (Note ) WatchKit: -[SPGizmoAppServer notifyClientsExtensionTerminated:] Companion app extension died - killing gizmo app com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch PhotoGauge WatchKit App[238] <Warning>: -[SPApplicationDelegate extensionDidTerminate:] WatchKit App killed by WatchKit daemon
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch iap2d[168] <Warning>: process com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp.watchkitextension is now terminated
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp[0xaeb3][238]) <Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch Carousel[30] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp[0xaeb3]' exited voluntarily.
Sep 16 09:21:30 Andrews-AppleWatch Carousel[30] <Warning>: Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
Sep 16 09:21:31 Andrews-AppleWatch iap2d[168] <Warning>: process com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp is now switching to other state
Sep 16 09:21:31 Andrews-AppleWatch iap2d[168] <Warning>: process com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp is now terminated
Sep 16 09:21:31 Andrews-AppleWatch UserEventAgent[22] <Warning>: 68344732102: id=com.AndrewMoore.PhotoGauge.watchkitapp pid=238, state=0
Sep 16 09:21:31 Andrews-AppleWatch ReportCrash[240] <Warning>: report not saved because it is non-actionable
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Removed and reinstalled app multiple times
- Attempted relaunching the app multiple times after being deployed from Xcode to make sure it wasn't just Xcode failing to launch for some reason.
- Double-checked that the class and module are properly set on each interface controller [image: This is correct]
- Ensured that the iOS app, Watch App, and Watch App Extensions plist files have the proper values for WKAppBundleIdentifier, WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier, etc.
- Double-checked that all the files in my WatchKit Extension have the proper target membership

[image]

I am truly running out of ideas at this point. My guess is that there is some glaring simple thing that I must be doing wrong, but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved this issue. The real reason that the app would not launch is because it was not launching fast enough, so the daemon killed the process. Each of my three pickers had been attempting to load ~20 images to use in sequence. This was easy for the simulator to handle, but proved too much for the physical device.